# ¿Se puede meter una funcion dentro de otra funcion?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Lo que tengo que conseguir es que al darle al botón me guarde el nombre en MYSQL mediante POST(tengo el boton comentado)y al darle me salte a window.print() o a una función que te saque la impresión en pdf con el nombre que he puesto en el formulario.
Y lo que se me ha ocurrido es meter la función window.print dentro de la funcion myFunction(), pero se me quedaría colgando lo de guardar datos, porque si no me equivoco para eso se necesita poner en el button de type="submit"
Gracias de antemano

```js
function myFunction() {
    let producto = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1").value;
    document.getElementById("nombrePoner").innerHTML = producto;
}
```

```css
 #contenedor{
        background-color: red;
        width: 150px;
    }
    #nombrePoner{
        background-color: rosybrown;
        
        width: 200px;
    }
```

```html
    <title>Document</title>

    <form method="" action="">
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="" aria- 
    describedby="emailHelp">
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="printPDF" onClick="myFunction();">Guardar dato e imprimir</button>
        <!-- <button type="submit" id="printPDF" onClick="myFunction();">Generar datos</button> -->
    </form>
    <div id="contenedor">
        Mi nombre es 
        <div id="nombrePoner"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, puedes poner una función dentro de otra función sin problema. Para solucionar el problema del envío, puedes usar la función `submit()`. Dentro de tu función, luego de hacer todo lo que necesitas puedes seleccionar el formulario y enviarlo:

```
document.getElementById('id_del_formulario').submit();
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado, gracias.

Comment: ¿Y si quiero que cuando vaya escribiendo el nombre en el formulario, me vaya rellenando a la vez en el div como podría hacerlo?Gracias

Comment: Puedes registrar un `onchange` en el input y asignar el valor en el div